# Transfer TableviewCell to AnotherTableView in swift

Tags: swift

I have two tableView (FavouriteViewController and MainViewController) controllers in my project and the ViewController connected through segue with button. I have some data running in my MainViewController and the FavouriteViewController basically with no data in it.I am trying to transfer tableViewCell when the cell clicked from MainViewController to favouriteViewController using tableViewCell swipe action method or any another suggeste method.

my codes as below.

My MainViewController

```
var arrays = ["Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Phill","Below","Above","Clean",]

var sendSelectedData = NSString()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    title = "FavTV"

    let titlebutton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 32))
    titlebutton.setTitle("Quote", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    titlebutton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "PartyLetPlain", size: 35)
    titlebutton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    titlebutton.addTarget(self, action: "titlePresed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titlebutton

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell1")
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

func titlePressed() {

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowDetails", sender: nil)
        segue.destinationViewController as! favTableViewController
    }
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowDetails", sender: nil)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!

sendSelectedData = (currentCell.textLabel?.text)! as String

 //self.arrays.append(String(indexPath.row)
// performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowDetails", sender: self)

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle,forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}

    ///////////////////////
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle,forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        switch editingStyle {
        case .Delete:
            // remove the deleted item from the model
            self.arrays.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowDetails", sender: self)

            tableView.reloadData()


        default:
            return
        }
}
    /////////////////////

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

if (segue.identifier == "ShowDetails") {

    // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
    let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! favTableViewController
    // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
    viewController.arrayx = [sendSelectedData as String]

    ///////////////////////
    self.arrays.append(sendSelectedData as String)
    /////////////////////


}
```

}

My FavouriteTableView:

```
var arrayx = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

title = "Fav"

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayx.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = arrayx[indexPath.row] as? String 

    return cell

}
}
```

Above code works in a simple way  when i press the cell from MainViewController and then when the titlePressed() button pressed. it passing the pressed cell data to FavouriteTableView....

I need some suggetion how to transfer cell to my FavouriteTableView permanently.I am not sure about my logic is right. Please some one point me the right direction.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: you can see this example to drag and drop cells between different collection views https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/kddraganddropcollectionview

Comment: You are on the right track. I am not sure what you mean by " transfer cell to my FavouriteTableView permanently".  What is shown in a table is driven by the data in that table. If you want make it permanent, then adjust the data accordingly.

Comment: @ryantxr Thanks for your response. I mean Moving tableViewCell from one tableView to another TableView.

Comment: In that case, you would not move over the actual UITableViewCell object itself. You would remove the data from the one table and insert the data into the other table. Then both tables would render themselves showing the cell in table2 instead of table1 where it was before.

Comment: @ryantxr Your right mate. Please point me a direction.i am looking for the solution for a long while and I spend some time with Googling it and searching and searching still couldn't get the answer...thanks

Comment: @joe, you are already there.  Look at your `arrayx`. That is the data for your table. You need to add your data to that. And you would remove the item from the other table (which you didn't post)

Comment: @ryantxr i updated the code.now i can able to delete row and insert the deleted row in the same tableview not the next tableview . still i can't figure it out how to move row to my fav tableview. i struck here. let me know your suggestion or sample code...

Comment: Change the underlying data then refresh the table. `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: @ryantxr  can you elaborate but more. I am not sure what you mean  by underlying data(which data I have to modify ?).i am so  desperately to find the answer. Can you please provide some example...thanks

Answer (score 1):

What shows up in a table is driven by :

```
var arrayx = [] // <-- CHANGE THE CONTENTS OF THIS ARRAY
```

Change the data in that array and then reload the table.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Here is your function that gets the data and puts it into the cells.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    // arrayx is the data that drives the table.
    // changing the data in arrayx will cause the table to show different data.


    // **********************************************
    // ** The table will show whatever is in arrayx
    // ** therefore, if you change arrayx then table
    // ** will have that new data.
    // **********************************************
    cell.textLabel?.text = arrayx[indexPath.row] as? String 
    // **********************************************


    return cell

}
```